# Mean Absolute Error (MAE) derivative

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative, mae

$$MAE=|y_\textrm{pred} - y_\textrm{true}|$$

$$\dfrac{\mathrm dMAE}{\mathrm dy_\textrm{pred}} = ?$$

I'm trying to understand how MAE works as a loss function in neural networks using backpropogation. I know it can be used directly in some APIs - e.g. [Keras](https://keras.io/losses/) - however I see [tensorflow doesn't allow it](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12252) (although you can manually declare it `tf.abs(tf.minus(y_pred,y_true))`).

My question is: How is the derivative of MAE generally calculated (I only found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3828837_On_error_backpropagation_algorithm_using_absolute_error_function) which uses an apparently complex approximation) and specifically how is it computed in tensorflow (when manually declaring) and keras?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [mae](/questions/tagged/mae), as a function of $y_{\text{pred}}$, is not differentiable at $y_{\text{pred}}=y_{\text{true}}$. Elsewhere, the derivative is $\pm 1$ by a straightforward application of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):

$$\dfrac{d\text{MAE}}{dy_{\text{pred}}} = 
\begin{cases}
  +1,\quad y_{\text{pred}}>y_{\text{true}}\\
  -1,\quad y_{\text{pred}}<y_{\text{true}}
\end{cases}$$

The interpretation is straightforward: if you are predicting too high ($y_{\text{pred}}>y_{\text{true}}$), then increasing $y_{\text{pred}}$ yet more by one unit will increase the MAE by an equal amount of one unit, so the gradient encourages you to *reduce* $y_{\text{pred}}$. And vice versa if $y_{\text{pred}}<y_{\text{true}}$.

Skimming the paper you link, it seems like they approximate the MAE by a differentiable function to avoid the "kink" at $y_{\text{pred}}=y_{\text{true}}$.

As to what specifically is implemented in TensorFlow and keras, that is off-topic here. Best to consult the documentation, the source code or any specific help community.

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing implementations are programmed to default to either +1 or -1 if y_pred=y_true, I'm sure I've read somewhere that's how the Relu is normally handled.

Comment: But doesn't this mean that the weighted increase or decrease is independent of the magnitude of the error?

Comment: @PranitBankar: yes indeed. If you are at any point that is different from the minimum, moving towards the minimum will reduce the MAE value - and the amount of the reduction does not depend on where you started.

Answer (score 1):

As for Tensorflow's Keras here is the good answer:

[TensorFlow or Theano: how do they know the loss function derivative based on the neural network graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35344963)

And if we will dig into the source code we will see that it uses math_ops.sign wich is return 0 for 0:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c91e944d626b517781af6a63c0aee302ab2457e3/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py#L577

Answer (score 1):

In this way, we can use **Subgradient method**

**Subgradient descent**
$$w^{t+1}=\ w^t-\alpha g$$

$$g=\begin{cases}1& x> 0 \\ [-1,1] & x=0\\-1 & x<0\end{cases}$$

Derivation of MAE with L1 and L2 regularization
$$MAE=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left|y_{pred}-y_{true}\right| \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,{(\left|u\right|)}^′=\frac{uu^′}{\left|u\right|}$$

|  |  | L1 | L2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $$MAE=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left|\left(w_1x+w_0\right)-y^i\right|$$ | + | $$\frac{\lambda}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|w_j\right|$$ | $$\frac{\lambda}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_j^2$$ |
| $$\frac{dMAE}{dw_1}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\frac{w_1x+w_0-y^i}{\left|\left(w_1x+w_0\right)-y^i\right|}\left(x\right)}$$ | + | $$\lambda\frac{w_j}{\left|w_j\right|}$$ | $$2\lambda w_j$$ |
| $$\frac{dMAE}{dw_0}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\frac{w_1x+w_0-y^i}{\left|\left(w_1x+w_0\right)-y^i\right|}\left(1\right)}$$ | + | - | - |

Comment: Hi. Where is this snapshot of the page taken from? From a book? From a lecture note? If it is so, please cite the reference.

Comment: @User1865345 no I wrote it by myself in MSWord and then took a snapshot of that, cause I couldn't write a formula in the answer.

Comment: Very well. Thanks for informing. In fact, this is a MathJax enabled site. You can typeset your equations here. For help, check [Instructions on how to use LaTeX on CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated).